# JQuery slideToggle() current show/hide state property?

Tags: jquery

What is the easiest way to programmatically find the current toggle state of a DOM element when using the slideToggle() function in jquery 1.3.2?

I expected there to be a property for this, but I can't seem to find one.  Directly checking the CSS display or height seems like a hack, but maybe that's what one is expected to do.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you can do something like this,

```
if($("#panel").is(":hidden"))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I had actually gone with checking the css display property, but this would be cleaner.

Comment: Note that ["After calling slideToggle(), hidden ALWAYS returns false regardless of the state.](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/state-of-slidetoggle). Just be sure to check `is(":hidden"))` before calling `.slideToggle();`.

Comment: Thanks @AdamHuffman, had that exact problem and calling it before fixed it.

Comment: @AdamHuffman checking :hidden in a callback function from slidetoggle() gives the final state after a slidetoggle has taken place, e.g. `$(element).slideToggle(function(){ var final_state = $(this).is(':hidden') ? 'hidden' : 'visible'; console.log(final_state);});`